# CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl redirecting to incorrect url on upload

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, file-upload

I have a wordpress multi-site install running on GAE, everything works great for the most part.

I want users to upload files via the front-end to a custom file handler at {customdomain.com}/app/client/{client_id}/upload_profile_image/ (I'm using rewrite rules)

This works on a non-app-engine setup (apache/php) but when I am using the GCS uploader I seem to get redirected to the main site domain at this url: {maindomain}/wp-signup.php?new=

This is the code based on the code for the wp google-app-engine plugin:

```
    $url = site_url('/app/client/' . $Client->ID . '/upload_profile_image/');
    require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
    $options = [
         'gs_bucket_name' => get_option('appengine_uploads_bucket', ''),
         'url_expiry_time_seconds' => 60 * 60 * 24, // One day is the maximum
    ];
    $wp_maxupsize = wp_max_upload_size();
    // set max_bytes_per_blob option only if max upload size is a positive int
    if (is_int($wp_maxupsize) && $wp_maxupsize > 0) {
       $options['max_bytes_per_blob'] = $wp_maxupsize;
    }
    // Setup internal authentication
    $sign_result = \google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService::signForApp(AUTH_KEY . get_current_user_id());
    $url = add_query_arg('gae_auth_user', get_current_user_id(), $url);
    $url = add_query_arg('gae_auth_key', $sign_result['key_name'], $url);
    $url = add_query_arg('gae_auth_signature', urlencode(base64_encode($sign_result['signature'])), $url);

     $url = \google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl($url,$options);
```

When I submit the file (via drag/drop using dropzone) I see the following requests:

```
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:49190
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytVOWWgs3diiHzPNF
Cookie: {cookies}
Host:{customdomain}
Origin:http://{customdomain}
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://{customdomain}/app/client/27/view/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

The reply is this:

```
Alternate-Protocol:80:quic,p=0.5,80:quic,p=0.5
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 17 Mar 2015 03:07:53 GMT
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Location:http://{maindomain}/wp-signup.php?new=
Pragma:no-cache
Server:UploadServer ("Built on Mar 6 2015 11:14:41 (1425669281)")
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars:$0.000009
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage:ms=174 cpu_ms=22
```

Which fails the upload and I get this in the console: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://{maindomain}/wp-signup.php?new=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://{customdomain}' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Here is my app.yaml:

```
application: 
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "1h"

inbound_services:
  - warmup

handlers:
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: wordpress/favicon.ico
  upload: wordpress/favicon.ico

- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|svg|ttf|eot|woff|swf))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|svg|ttf|eot|woff|swf)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php

- url: /wp-multi-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-multi-cron.php

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php

- url: /wp-admin/network/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/network/index.php

- url: /wp-admin/network/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/network/\1

- url: /([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*\.(htm.*$|html.*$|css.*$|js.*$|ico.*$|jpg.*$|png.*$|gif.*$|woff.*$|ttf.*$|eot.*$|svg.*$))
  static_files: wordpress/\2
  upload: wordpress/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*\.(htm.*$|html.*$|css.*$|js.*$|ico.*$|jpg.*$|png.*$|gif.*$|woff.*$|ttf.*$|eot.*$|svg.*$))
  application_readable: true


pagespeed:
  domains_to_rewrite:
  url_blacklist:
  enabled_rewriters:
  - LeftTrimUrls
  disabled_rewriters:
  - CombineCss
  - CombineJs
  - MoveCssToHead

skip_files:
- wordpress/wp-content/uploads/.*
- ^(.*/)?.*/.svn/.*$
```

I'm at a loss on what could be the issue. Regular uploads via the WP backend work fine, so it has to be something I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml file as well?

Comment: HI Mars, I've edited the original question.

Comment: You're missing a handler for /app/client/{client_id}/upload_profile_image/? What was your original rewrite rule?

Comment: I'm handling those with WP rewrites. (add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: On an unrelated note, the handlers after /(.+)?/? will never get hit.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. That explains a couple of things.

Comment: @Mars I've corrected my app.yaml and even tried to use a different upload URL to a direct file(avoiding the rewrites) and I am getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, as I suspected it was something I was doing wrong.

For brevity I omitted some if statements that caused $url to be empty before being passed to 'CreateUploadUrl' which is why after the upload it was being redirected to the default site.

This is what happens when you code late into the night after a long day.